# Deploying beego application in openshift

Tags: go, openshift, beego

I've created a go application in openshift using the go cartridge but when I've updated my code to use beego when I push it I keep getting errors like:

`An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)` and `Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build'`

In my app.conf I've set the host and the port base on what openshift will provide.
httphost = os.Getenv("HOST")
httpport = os.Getenv("PORT")

But I still getting the errors mention above.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: When the cartridge is built, any errors from the build will be logged in the application's log. Check the log in `~/app-root/logs` when ssh'd into the application for further information on what could be causing this.

Comment: Hello @Timbabwe I just check the logs and I only see haproxy.log and haproxy_ctld.log and when I opened it is just say that gear is down for maintenance but there's no log about the build error or why it's not building. Do you have some suggestion on this? Thanks

Comment: I've just saw https://github.com/eims/openshift-beego now it's working the only problem is that DIY is not designed to scale for now.